# Can git show only specifically which commits were merged into master?

Tags: git

When I have a rolling `dev` branch, and then once I get to a point where some significant work has been done and is stable, and I merge that into `master`, the git log will show the entire development log as a straight line. I can only tell how many commits there are between `dev` and `master` currently, but all the previous commits don't differentiate between whether they have been merged into `master`, or just "skipped" so to say.

But could I get `git` to show me at which commits specifically the `dev` has been merged into `master`, and which commits were only progress made in `dev`, for example something like this:

```
* (HEAD -> dev)
* (master)
|\
| *
| *
|/
* ((here dev was merged into master))
|\
| *
| *
| *
|/
* init
```

Preferably in `--graph` context, since it would be the most intuitive way to perceive the information.

---

**EDIT**: More detail, hopefully makes the question clearer.

If I init git right now and create my first commit, let's say the hash for it is `0000001`. Then I create my `dev` branch, do some work on it, and I keep commiting my work-in-progress.

My first commit in the `dev` branch is hash `0000002`, the next one is `0000003`, and the next `0000004`.

At this point, if I merge the `0000004` to `master`, what I would like to know is that `master` went straight from `0000001` to `0000004`. That is what I meant by `master` having "skipped" `0000002` and `0000003`, as in, those were at no point in time active states of the `master` branch. (I'm sorry if there is proper terminology for that situation, I'm not familiar with it, but I hope you know what I mean).

In this situation, my ideal result would be to see my `git log` (in graph mode) as:

```
* 0000004 (HEAD -> master, dev)
|\
| * 0000003
| * 0000002
|/
* 0000001
```

What `git` shows me instead in this case is a straight line, so I wouldn't know from looking at the `git log` that there was ever a point where one branch was on the `0000002` commit, and the other one wasn't (or that there were even two branches at that point in time).

So `git` currently shows this scenario like this:

```
* 0000004 (HEAD -> master, dev)
* 0000003
* 0000002
* 0000001
```

Comment: Can you formalize a bit what exactly is "skipped so to say"? What particular commits, reachable from the current DEV head, you do not want to see in git log? Maybe you can create minimal graph (in ASCII or actual github demo) which shows, which commit shall be excluded and which shall not?

Comment: @sbat I've edited with a more detailed example, hopefully this illustrates well what I was hoping to say?

Comment: Isn't this just `git log --graph --oneline master`? You can also use [tig](https://jonas.github.io/tig/).

Comment: You could use `gitk` for this, or an IDE with `git` capabilities

Comment: @RaulRene Does this also mean `git` alone definitely does not do this on its own?

Comment: @DigitalNinja it does keep track differently, not sure if you can see it the way you want it just with `--graph`. Maybe you can but I never bothered. I always install `gitk` when setting up a new machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on the updated description, the likely culprit of the problem is **fast forward merge** https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

If fast-forward merge is allowed, merge commit 000004 was simply not created if no changes are done on master. Master branch ref was just moved to the dev branch ref, and the history you hope to see simply does not exist in your repository.

If you need to maintain this history for whatever reason, you have to merge to master with fast-forward merge disabled either in merge command itself (`--no-ff` flag), or on repo level. In this case the `git log --graph` will indeed display the history as you expect, see the example output for the example repo.

```
$ git log --graph
*   commit 4990d96a77e12206481eaead37a4283a42e49c64 (HEAD -> master)
|\  Merge: 76ef670 7cf0f0e
| | Date:   Tue Oct 8 15:39:37 2019 +0400
| |
| |     Merge branch 'testbranch'
| |
| * commit 7cf0f0e3c6ffe899867991ab88e642b5d9b58b49 (testbranch)
|   Date:   Tue Oct 8 15:38:36 2019 +0400
|
|       Test change on the branch
|
* commit 76ef670aa946bd02eaefed210a8fdeb57d5fbfff
  Date:   Tue Oct 8 15:38:01 2019 +0400

      Initial commit
```

Answer (score 0):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/cmbuckley/bd495a3b891396cd4dc30a87e54d7084) demonstrates how you can do this using git:

```
git log --graph --oneline master
```

Also, have a look at [tig](https://jonas.github.io/tig/), which is a great text interface for git.

In this case, `master` branch does contain the other commits, but the difference with a recursive (non-fast-forward) merge is that it contains 2 parents, not 1:

```
$ git show f73dd5d
commit f73dd5d
Merge: bdc04c9 7f79a4d # 2 commits
```

The "activity" on `master` was to create a merge commit `f73dd5d` based on the previous commit `bdc04c9`, but merging in the contents of `7f79a4d`.

Comment: It's just the `--no-ff` parameter that makes that difference, that's why I didn't get you from your initial comment, and I had to play around with that gist to finally understand why your code did what i wanted, and my previous tests didn't. So I would have eventually gotten it working with your help, but the other response was more to the point, which is why i'm accepting that one, but thanks for taking the time though!